# Selenium stopped working with the error message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'Allow')]"}

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This code used to work:

```
time.sleep(3)

driver.switch_to.window(window_facebook)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"email\"]").send_keys(fb_email)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"pass\"]").send_keys(fb_pass)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"login\"]").click()

driver.switch_to.window(window_tinder)

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Allow')]").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'ALLOW')]").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label=\"Allow\"]").click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Not interested')]").click()
```

This used to work, but now it stopped working with the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'Allow')]"}
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Allow')]").click()
```

Screenshots:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol4zA.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBPQ5.jpg

Comment: Hard coded sleep time is not a good practice to use. Did you tried to wait until the element is visible on the screen ? In your screenshot its visible but just to make sure.

Comment: if it was working previously then why dont you try to add WebDriverWait before performing click action. it could be possible server is taking time to load the page

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above server might taking time to load your page. Try below code and check if its working for you.

**Imports required**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
```

**Code with WebDriverWait**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Allow')]")))
element.click()
```